# Lighttpd proxy curl GET does not close connection

Tags: http, curl, lighttpd

I have lighttpd set up to reverse proxy requests to a certain URL. The lighttpd.conf file looks like this:

```
server.modules = (
    default modules,
    "mod_proxy",
)

$HTTP["url"] =~ "(^/myurl)" {
    proxy.server = ( "" => ( "" => ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 8080 )))
}
```

The proxy forwards requests for /myurl to my custom backend software.

I have noticed that proxied GET requests always have

```
Connection: close
```

in the request header. As a consequence the proxied connection seems to be closed after each request. Is there a way to force this to

```
Connection: Keep-alive
```

?

Comment: Which lighttpd version do you use?

Comment: 1.4.45 - sorry should have mentioned that in question.

Comment: Take a look here: https://serverfault.com/a/309295/217116

Comment: Ok seems I need lighttpd 1.5. Amazing that your link was from 2009 and Debian stretch is still on lighttpd 1.4.x!

Comment: Actually, looking at the lighttpd web page https://www.lighttpd.net/ it looks like lighttpd is up to 1.4.51. Following the links to the lighttpd documentation it seems that the lighttpd 1.5.x branch is now dead: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxyCore

Comment: lighttpd mod_proxy intentionally sends Connection: close. This is not configurable.  Used a as a reverse proxy, lighttpd is generally physically close to the backend servers.  When there are multiple servers, lighttpd can be configured to spread the load among the backends.  While there can be a marginal benefit to keep-alive connections to the backends, that is not likely to be your performance bottleneck unless you're serving static files.  If you're serving static files, then lighttpd could serve the static files instead of being a reverse proxy.